# Sympy error: The function cannot be automatically detected for -k*x

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to make a script to calculate the eigen states/energy levels of a simple harmonic oscillator using sympy.

This is a system that exhibits periodic motion, such as a mass on a spring. In general, the equation of motion for a simple harmonic oscillator can be written as:

#### `F = -kx`

where:

- **F** is the force on the oscillator.
- **k** is the spring constant.
- **x** is the displacement from the equilibrium position.

The eigenvalues of a simple harmonic oscillator are the possible energy levels of the system. For a simple harmonic oscillator, the eigenvalues are given by:

#### `E_n = (n + 1/2) \* h \* nu`

where:

- **n** is an integer representing the energy level
- **h** is the **Planck** constant
- **nu** is the frequency of the oscillator.

These eigenvalues are equally spaced and form a discrete spectrum, which is a characteristic property of quantum systems.

```py
import sympy as sym

# Define the variables and the equation of motion
x, k, m, h, nu,t = sym.symbols('x k m h nu t')
eq = sym.Eq(-k * x, m * sym.diff(x,t, 2))

# Solve the equation of motion for the displacement x(t)
sol = sym.dsolve(eq)

# Compute the eigenvalues of the oscillator
E = sym.solve(sym.det(sol.lhs - nu * sym.eye(2)), nu)

# Print the eigenvalues
print(E)
```

where the code defines the displacement (x), spring constant (k), mass (m), Planck constant (h), and frequency (nu) as symbolic variables, and then uses these variables to define the equation of motion for a simple harmonic oscillator.

I am however getting this error and cannot find a way to debug it.

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 8>()
      5 eq = sym.Eq(-k * x, m * sym.diff(x,t, 2))
      7 # Solve the equation of motion for the displacement x(t)
----> 8 sol = sym.dsolve(eq)
     10 # Compute the eigenvalues of the oscillator
     11 E = sym.solve(sym.det(sol.lhs - nu * sym.eye(2)), nu)

File /opt/python/3.9/envs/pulsar/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/solvers/ode/ode.py:605, in dsolve(eq, func, hint, simplify, ics, xi, eta, x0, n, **kwargs)
    602 given_hint = hint  # hint given by the user
    604 # See the docstring of _desolve for more details.
--> 605 hints = _desolve(eq, func=func,
    606     hint=hint, simplify=True, xi=xi, eta=eta, type='ode', ics=ics,
    607     x0=x0, n=n, **kwargs)
    608 eq = hints.pop('eq', eq)
    609 all_ = hints.pop('all', False)

File /opt/python/3.9/envs/pulsar/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/solvers/deutils.py:180, in _desolve(eq, func, hint, ics, simplify, prep, **kwargs)
    178 # preprocess the equation and find func if not given
    179 if prep or func is None:
--> 180     eq, func = _preprocess(eq, func)
    181     prep = False
    183 # type is an argument passed by the solve functions in ode and pde.py
    184 # that identifies whether the function caller is an ordinary
    185 # or partial differential equation. Accordingly corresponding
    186 # changes are made in the function.

File /opt/python/3.9/envs/pulsar/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/solvers/deutils.py:82, in _preprocess(expr, func, hint)
     80     funcs = set().union(*[d.atoms(AppliedUndef) for d in derivs])
     81     if len(funcs) != 1:
---> 82         raise ValueError('The function cannot be '
     83             'automatically detected for %s.' % expr)
     84     func = funcs.pop()
     85 fvars = set(func.args)

ValueError: The function cannot be automatically detected for -k*x
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print out the different quantities in your expression to debug what is happening. Your equation is

```
In [5]: eq
Out[5]: -k⋅x = 0
```

I'm guessing that's not what you intended it to be. The reason is this:

```
In [6]: diff(x, t, 2)
Out[6]: 0
```

That's because `x` as a symbol does not depend on `t` so as far as differentiating wrt to `t` it is a constant and its derivative is zero. You should make `x` be a function of `t`:

```
In [7]: x = Function('x')

In [10]: eq = Eq(-k*x(t), m*diff(x(t), t, 2))

In [11]: eq
Out[11]: 
              2      
             d       
-k⋅x(t) = m⋅───(x(t))
              2      
            dt       

In [12]: dsolve(eq)
Out[12]: 
                  _____             _____
                 ╱ -k              ╱ -k  
           -t⋅  ╱  ───        t⋅  ╱  ─── 
              ╲╱    m           ╲╱    m  
x(t) = C₁⋅ℯ             + C₂⋅ℯ
```

If you were hoping to see `sin` and `cos` there then the issue is that you haven't said anything about the symbols `k` and `m`:

```
In [13]: k, m = symbols('k, m', positive=True)

In [14]: eq = Eq(-k*x(t), m*diff(x(t), t, 2))

In [15]: dsolve(eq)
Out[15]: 
             ⎛√k⋅t⎞         ⎛√k⋅t⎞
x(t) = C₁⋅sin⎜────⎟ + C₂⋅cos⎜────⎟
             ⎝ √m ⎠         ⎝ √m ⎠
```